# Customize Wordpress Woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I am fairly new to Woocommerce, but I have an idea for a website, which would include some customization of this plugin. My idea is that instead of products, there could be some other type of data stored in the database like pictures for example. Instead of buying these products people could just put a "like" on them, but towards the engine it would register as a buy. This way I could take advantage of built-in functions like sorting for the most popular items. Is it a good idea or should I consider some other way? Thank you!

Comment: WooCommerce is kind of big... let's just put it this way, you want to use a samurai sword where you could just use a knife..

Answer (score 1):

For images I would be more inclined to look at something like [a Pinterest style theme](http://athemes.com/collections/best-pinterest-style-wordpress-themes/).

Comment: I dont think he was asking for a theme?!